# Checking if a word is in a text file in Python

Tags: python

I'm not sure why my code won't work. Can anyone help?

```
userinp = str(input("What is wrong with your phone?\n"))
with open("keywords.txt", "r") as solution:
    for line in solution:
        if userinp in line:
            print("in list")
        else:
            print("not in list")
```

My 'keywords.txt' only contains the word wet.

Every time i put 'wet' in the IDLE, it says it is in the list. However, when I put 'Phone is wet', it says 'Not in list'

Thanks for any help

Comment: Everything below the `with` line should be indented. Why do you have a line that just says `for`?

Comment: I edited it to how the code actually looks

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: It looks like you have something that will print "in list" or "not in list" for every line in the file. If it's not doing what you want, please describe the problem or error you are having.

Comment: Edited to specify the problem

Comment: The string "Phone is wet" is not contained in the string "wet". You need to put some more thought into what your program is actually supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran exactly the same code with some lines content in the keywords.txt file:-

userinp = str(input("What is wrong with your phone?\n"))
with open("keywords.txt", "r") as solution:
    for line in solution:
        if userinp in line:
            print("in list")
        else:
            print("not in list")

Works absolutely fine. Only error I noticed was input() as I am using python 2.7 Apart from that the output was fine. After every iteration it prints whether it's in line or not in line.

As per your new updates, when there is 'wet' in the txt file and you searched 'phone is wet', It's obvious that this sentence is not there in that line! However the other way round will work!